# Nuaces of meaning, depending on which part is in the instrumental case in "Последним его словом было мое имя"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> 1) **Последним его словом** было мое имя.
>
> 2) Мое имя было **последним его словом** .
>
> 3) **Моим именем** было последнее его слово.
>
> 4) Последнее его слово было **моим именем**.

I'm assuming you can phrase this sentence in at least four different ways, but  how do they compare in terms of nuance and emphasis?

Incidentally, I wonder if the different positions of "его" affect the meaning of the sentence at all: "последним его словом" vs "его последним словом"?

Comment: Putting "слово" at the end, like in #2 (and #3, though it's not proper) expands the range of possibilities (A trial defense? A kind of final decision? A conversation that ended abruptly?), while putting it up front creates a stronger impression that the person has died, and that word was the last word of his life. Putting "последним" to the very front adds gravity to it.

Comment: 3 and 4 imply (and 3 implies it really strong) that I was named after what was his last word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Последним его словом было мое имя.

This sounds neutral: "His last word was my name."

> 2. Мое имя было последним его словом.

This might give the impression that your name killed him. :)

> 3. Моим именем было последнее его слово.

This is a sort of Yoda-speak: "My name his last word was".

> 4. Последнее его слово было моим именем.

This sounds OK. Almost as good as No.1.

Comment: Just to be sure: In "Последним его словом было **мое имя**", "мое имя" is the subject, right? Interesting how the different word orders give such different impressions!

Comment: That's right, "мое имя" is the subject. Different word order *and* different case markings.

Answer (score 5):

```
1) Последним его словом было мое имя.
```

Emphasis on `мое имя`. ("Последним его словом было мое имя, а не что-то другое")

```
2) Мое имя было последним его словом .
```

Emphasis on `последним его словом`, especially on `последним`. ("Мое имя было последним его словом, а не первым или, например, третьим с конца.")

```
3) Моим именем было последнее его слово.
```

This is hard to comprehend. It sounds for me like a gothic litherary style.

```
4) Последнее его слово было моим именем.
```

Like 1. Also, it sounds a bit like there is a queer coincidence between his last word and the narrator's name.

Comment: As for variant 3, it's rather easy to imagine a situation in which that could be said. Imagine a murderer who was arrested because his dying victim called his name as his last word. Now in a prison cell, in desperation he's slamming his fists on the wall and shouting, "МОИМ ИМЕНЕМ было последнее его слово". The capitals mean shouting. And that's a drama in verses, and the next lines are something like "Потом растаяло оно на его устах. / Часы размеренно били полвосьмого, / Ну а меня наполнял безотчётный страх". What I mean, #3 is a very emphatic sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Nos. 1 and 4 are plain, narrative variants, slightly emphasising "his last word" meaning and differing in grammar only.

No. 2 changes emphasis to "my name", stays in the narrative style.

No. 3 reorders the words and because of this the phrase gets "dramatic". Emphasis may be put either on "his last word" or on "my name" by intonation, when spoken/read, or by typographic means, when written/printed.